# Find cells with more than one email and separate them into different tables with all of the other information the same

Tags: php, mysql, xml

BEFORE

```
ID  |  NAME  | ADDRESS              |   EMAIL
===============================================================================
1   | Bob    | 999 bob street, UK   | bob@email.com
2   | Jimmy  | 123 jimmy house, USA | jimmy@email.com jimmy-partner@email.com
```

Ok so here is my problem, I have 10,000+ rows looking like ID 1 & 2. 
Some of them even have 3-6 emails per cell when most of them should only have one.

I need a way that will select rows that have 2 or more emails, copy the whole row and replace the copied row with one of the 2 emails so they have their own separate row.

AFTER

```
ID  |  NAME  | ADDRESS              |   EMAIL
===============================================================================
1   | Bob    | 999 bob street, UK   | bob@email.com
2   | Jimmy  | 123 jimmy house, USA  | jimmy@email.com
3   | Jimmy  | 123 jimmy house, USA | jimmy-partner@email.com
```

**Thank You everyone for all your suggestions as they all provide useful information that can be used in the future.**

Comment: i wouldn't, you should create a separate email table with user_id,email. in your solution if Jimmy moved house you would update 2 rows, with mine only one.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?  It would probably make more sense to extract the emails into another table so there isn't so much repeated data.  This is a clear example of a one-to-many relationship between two entities.

Comment: Why do you need a table like that? 1st of all you haven't tried anything, 2nd is you ask for the whole code, 3rd even you achieve this, your data would be very ambiguous by having multiple `NAME`, `ID` and `ADDRESS` just for the `EMAIL`.

Comment: it would be better and less headache to move emails to a separate table. Then you can join them based on unique id's

Comment: @David Well lets say you are some big company that decided to use Excel to store all their customer information, and now you want to have everything stored into a MySQL table and one of the guys working on the Excel part put multiple emails per cell. Thats when you start having problems because 40% of them have 2+ emails per cell and when you want to send an email to them you are going to have issues.

Comment: @Understalker: None of that changes the fact that this is a one-to-many relationship.  Just because it hasn't been fixed yet doesn't mean it shouldn't be fixed.  The *reason* you're having these problems is because the design is wrong.  Fixing the design is how to address that.

Comment: @Understalker, that's the reason why you are hired. No offence meant but face the fact. It's true that the system must adjust but adjustments are for the better not for the worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the rows with more than one email by finding the rows that have more than one `@` in the EMAIL column:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table2 WHERE (LENGTH(EMAIL) - LENGTH(REPLACE(EMAIL, '@', ''))) > 1
```

Then you can process those result in PHP and add more rows as needed.

As mentioned in the comments, this might not be the best way to organize the data, but it does indeed address the question.

Play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1f77/10

Comment: +1 Good solution for isolating the multiples ... I was going to say like '% %' but this wont give you the false positives (leading/trailing spaces and such)

Comment: @immulatin I've tried something like this before, but it still will take over 20+ hours going through each one copying the table, delete one of the many email and repeat. But I think this has been the best one yet!

Comment: @Understalker You can script the update in PHP. Just a `foreach` on the results of the query. You just need to split the emails apart, update the current row with the first email, then insert a new row for every email after that. Shouldn't take the script long to run..

Comment: @Understalker: 20 hours to process 10,000+ rows?  Are you running this on an abacus?  This logic isn't the final solution, it's just a way to check for the presence of multiple emails.  You can use parts of the string logic here to actually extract those emails, and use those emails (and the IDs of the records from which they were selected) in `INSERT` statements into another table to hold the emails.  Should take a few seconds to run.

Comment: @David Take it easy on him, he came here for help.Everyone has gotta learn the rights and wrongs of the software world. If everyone knew every best practice we would've invented flying cars by now.

Comment: @David I was talking about doing it by hand after you got the list that has multiple emails. It took me about an hour last week to do ~300 rows and after I was finished I had 1000+ rows. Also some of them have semicolons, colons or had no spaces between the email that just took more time.

Comment: @Understalker: Maintaining data by hand is... not recommended.  For one thing, that much manual data work is very error prone.  More to the point, it's not a good use of your time.  Your goal here should be to select the individual emails from all of the records (which would require some string manipulation since the lists of emails are just one string), along with the IDs of the records, and insert records into a new table for the emails using the aforementioned IDs as a foreign key back to this table.

Answer (score 2):

Use ( lets call it contacts table )

```
ID  |  NAME  | ADDRESS              
====================================
1   | Bob    | 999 bob street, UK   
2   | Jimmy  | 123 jimmy house, USA
```

Join it with (lets say contacts_emails table):

```
ID  | Contact_id |   EMAIL
===============================================================================
1   | 1          | bob@email.com
2   | 2          | jimmy@email.com
3   | 2          | jimmy-partner@email.com
```

Comment: Well the thing is that some of the email cells have more than one email in each cell. So when you try to email Jimmy it will try to email "jimmy@email.com jimmy-partner@email.com"

Comment: @Understalker: That's the entire point of this design.  So one person can have multiple emails.  All you're doing is re-stating the problem that's solved with this answer.

Comment: @Understalker, why? You can't just send it. Fetching the emails is a different issue. I think this is the best solution but I suggest you name the table `Employee_email`.